# Python function design for arithmetic operations

Tags: python

Purpose:
*"Write a Python function that takes 3 numbers as arguments. Your
function should repeatedly subtract the second argument from the first
argument until the value is less than zero. Your function should then
print out this (negative) value."*

My suggested solution (What I have so far):

```
def subtraction(a, b, c):
    firstnum = a
    if firstnum > 0:
        firstnum = (a-b)
    if firstnum < 0:
        return firstnum
```

Problem: 
When I try it and the result is returned at the end, it comes up blank. Any suggestions for what I am missing?

Comment: Hi and welcome to [so]. Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site. It is not a discussion forum or a general help site. Users, such as yourself, ask questions and other users try to answer them. Your post is missing the essential element of a Stack Overflow post: the question!  Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: What you're missing is a loop.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? This is exactly how homework questions should be asked.

Comment: or maybe recursion

Comment: What I'm missing: What is the third argument for? "Write a function that takes 3 numbers as arguments." OK. "Repeatedly subtract the second from the first until the value is less than zero." OK. What happened to argument #3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to loop! As a result, you're not subtracting `b` from `a` until `a` is less than zero. I suggest using a while loop like this,

```
def subtraction(a, b, c):
    firstnum = a
    while firstnum >= 0:
         firstnum -= b
    return firstnum
```

Let me explain what was wrong before. Without the loop, your function would only subtract `b` from `a` once. Then it would check if `firstnum` was greater than zero. If AND only if `firstnum` was less than zero would it be returned. My guess is that `firstnum` would not be returned because it wouldn't be less than zero after one subtraction of `b`. With this loop, there will be a guarantee that `firstnum` will be returned as a negative value because the loop will keep subtracting `b` from `firstnum` until `firstnum` is less than zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
def subtraction(a,b,c):
    # why does c exist?
    return a % b - b
```

The smallest positive number achieved by repeated subtraction (repeated subtraction is division) is the modulus of the two  numbers. To find the next number, just subtract once more.

Unless you *have* to use a loop, but this seems like a homework question and I'm not sure if just giving the answer is the way to go about learning.